# How do I detect bitwise-moveable types using type traits in Visual C++ 9?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, types, type-traits

I have an `std::vector`-like class that is compiled with Visual C++ 2008. There's a piece in that class where stored elements are moved - either the body is reallocated or an insertion/partial erasure is done. Now some types can just be `memmove()`d while others need to be copy-constructed at the new location, then destroyed at the original location.

Currently there's a templated function that implements "copy-construct, then destroy" and there's a specialization for each type that can be `memmove()`d. I'd like to use V[isual C++ 2008 support of type traits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177194%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to simplify that task.

What I want is that for each POD `memmove()` is selected automatically. I don't mind if some types that can be `memmove()`d are moved using that templated function, but I can't tolerate the opposite situation - when a datatype that can't be `memmove()`d is `memmove()`d.

Looks like `__is_pod()` intrinsic will do, but MSDN says it returns `false` for built-in types. So I guess I need to also use `__is_class()` to first filter out non-classes.

So I though the following will do:

```
if( !__is_class(T) ) { // not a struct and not a class - built-in type
   //memmove()
} else if( __is_pod(T) ) { // is a struct or a class and is a POD
   //memmove()
} else { // is a struct or a class and is not a POD
   //DefaultMoveViaCopy()
}
```

Will my solution work okay?

Comment: `if( !__is_class(T) ||  __is_pod(T) ) { /*memmove()*/ } else { /*copy*/}`

Comment: You might want to peek at the `std::copy` implementation, which faces the same problem. See http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/552877/inefficient-std-copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using boost's enable_if:

```
template <typename T, class Enabler = void>
struct SmartCopy
{
    static void apply(const T& obj, T* dest)
    {
        // Generic copy...
    }
}

template <typename T>
struct SmartCopy<T, typename boost::enable_if_c<__is_pod(T) || !__is_class(T)>::type >
{
    static void apply(const T& obj, T* dest)
    {
        // memmove version...
    }
}

template <typename T>
void smart_move(const T& obj, T* dest)
{
    SmartCopy<T>::apply(obj, dest);
}
```